# How to extract the rest of a string starting with a substring in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

Data is something like this

```
MWF-ZoRyDL50.mp4
```

I want to extract the rest of the string after the hyphen character (-) so output will be

```
ZoRyDL50.mp4
```

It will be awesome if I can pass in a variable substring and the program can just extract the rest of the string after it.  So in this example, the input substring is `"MWF-"`

Do you how to do that in perl?  Thanks

```
my $string = 'MWF-ZoRyDL50.mp4'
my $input = 'MWF-'

$string =~ s/$input.*//;
```

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "extract the rest of the string after it". It's just a first incident or last issue. The rest is just handling Perl regex mechanics with variables in regex nonsense. The real issue is first/last, that's what counts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get rid of `.*`, that's matching the rest of the string and removing everything. You also should anchor with `^`  since you only want to match `$input` at the beginning.

And it's a good idea to use the `\Q` regexp operator in case `$input` contains any regexp metacharacters, so they'll be matched literally.

```
$string =~ s/^\Q$input//;
```

Comment: The hyphen example says they don't only want to match at the beginning, the MWF- example says they do.  So I don't think we know.

Comment: I only see one example, and it asks to remove the `MWF-` at the beginning.

Comment: And the title also says "starting with a substring".

Comment: The title is a bit ambiguous, but I understand it the same way, and it's easy to remove the `^` if they don't want it :)